# ¿Cómo adaptar una tabla html en dispositivo movil?

Tags: php, mysql

Hola amigos tengo este proyecto y necesito establecer una tabla que es esta:

[image: Es esta tabla]

El codigo es este:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
        <h2>VER ENTRADAS</h2>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-default">Agregar</a>
<br><br>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Agregar</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
<form role="form" method="post" action="php/agregar.php">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Nombre</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="lastname">Apellido</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="address">Domicilio</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" >
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="phone">Telefono</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" >
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Agregar</button>
</form>
        </div>

      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Como ven he utilizado Bootstrap y JQuery, todo funciona bien, pero mi problema es para adaptarlo a movil para que se muestre correctamente en pantalla.

Comment: Yo te recomendaría usar cartas(card's), es algo que siempre uso para mostrar información, cuando es mas de dos campos

Comment: @gilberto quintero y esto a que va con php?

Comment: Entonces el problema no es sobre php y mysql...

Answer (score 1):

Mostrar una tabla en móvil es complicado debido a la gran información que puede tener (dependiendo de sus columnas).

Prueba aplicando este css:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwPVNW

Comment: Muy interesante como cambia de lista total, a lista-carta, muy buen ejemplo.

Comment: Así como esta, esta respuesta es un comentario. Los links suelen romperse, para solucionarlo podrías agregar el snippet a tu respuesta y dejar el link como referencia a la _"fuente"_